# ¿Cómo simplificar varias consultas MySQL que tienen un mismo fin?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Necesito poder imprimir 5 datos que están enlazados al mismo autor, pero evaluar todo de manera general, es decir no quiero imprimir cuantos estudiantes están inscriptos en un curso sino el total de todos esos estudiantes que se hayan inscriptos en uno o en varios cursos del mismo autor y, así con todos los otros datos, por tema de prueba estoy probando con pocos registros, pero estos son los datos que deseo obtener:

```
Reseñas 2
Cursos 1
Proyectos 1
Estudiantes 1
Calificación del instructor 4.0
```

He guardado los datos de las tablas, que estoy utilizando: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s2uBnyTLgTXqADtVhkgEUv/0

Esta son las varias consultas que estoy empleando y, que si esta funcionando correctamente:

```
<?php
    $id_author = 1;
    $status_inscribed = "Completed";
    $study_program_intensive_instructor = "intensive";
    $study_program_proyect_instructor = "proyect";
    
    #Valoración general del instructor/autor
    $stmtVI = $con->prepare("SELECT AVG(ra.rating) AS avg_rating,
                                COUNT(ra.rating) valuations
                            FROM tbl_ratings ra
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_courses c ON ra.id_course = c.id_course
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_author a ON c.id_author = a.id_author
                            WHERE a.id_author=?
                            GROUP BY a.id_author");
    $stmtVI->bind_param("i", $id_author);
    $stmtVI->execute();
    $stmtVI->bind_result($avg_rating_instructor, $instructor_valuations);
    $stmtVI->fetch();
    $stmtVI->close();
    $avg_instructor_print = number_format($avg_rating_instructor,1);

    #Total de alumnos de manera general que tiene el instructor/autor
    $stmtEI = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(i.id_course)
                            FROM tbl_inscribed i
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_courses c ON i.id_course = c.id_course
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_author a ON c.id_author = a.id_author
                            WHERE a.id_author=? AND i.status=?
                            GROUP BY a.id_author");
    $stmtEI->bind_param("is", $id_author, $status_inscribed);
    $stmtEI->execute();
    $enrolled_instructor = 0;
    $stmtEI->bind_result($enrolled_instructor);
    $stmtEI->fetch();
    $stmtEI->close();

    #Total de cursos intensivos que tiene instructor/autor
    $stmtCII = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(c.id_course)
                            FROM tbl_courses c
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_author a ON c.id_author = a.id_author
                            WHERE c.id_author=? AND c.study_program=?
                            GROUP BY a.id_author");
    $stmtCII->bind_param("is", $id_author,$study_program_intensive_instructor);
    $stmtCII->execute();
    $course_intensive_instructor = 0;
    $stmtCII->bind_result($course_intensive_instructor);
    $stmtCII->fetch();
    $stmtCII->close();

    #Total de cursos proyectos que tiene el instructor/autor
    $stmtCIP = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(c.id_course)
                            FROM tbl_courses c
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_author a ON c.id_author = a.id_author
                            WHERE c.id_author=? AND c.study_program=?
                            GROUP BY a.id_author");
    $stmtCIP->bind_param("is", $id_author,$study_program_proyect_instructor);
    $stmtCIP->execute();
    $course_proyect_instructor = 0;
    $stmtCIP->bind_result($course_proyect_instructor);
    $stmtCIP->fetch();
    $stmtCIP->close();
?>
```

Como se puede observar en casi la mayoría se están repitiendo las mismas tablas y, sobre todo se basa en traer información del mismo autor `$id_author = 1;`

Lo he intentado unir las tablas, para unificar todo de la siguiente manera:

```
$id_author = 1;
$status_inscribed = "Completed";

$stmt =  $con->prepare("SELECT AVG(ra.rating) AS avg_rating,
                            COUNT(ra.rating) valuations,
                            COUNT(i.id_course) enrolled
                        FROM tbl_courses c
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_ratings ra ON ra.id_course = c.id_course
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_inscribed i ON i.id_course = c.id_course
                        WHERE c.id_author=? AND i.status=?
                        GROUP BY c.id_course, i.id_course");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $id_author, $status_inscribed);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($avg_rating_instructor, $total_instructor_review, $enrolled_instructor);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

Pero me imprime mal la información por ejemplo en la tabla `tbl_inscribed` existen dos registros uno que esta en estado `Completed` y el otro en estado `Pending` pero la variable `$enrolled_instructor` me imprime 3, cuando debería imprimir `1` por la condición pasada en el `WHERE`

He cambiado el orden de las tablas, pero tampoco https://ideone.com/LGExif he agregado diferentes maneras `GROUP BY a.id_author, i.status, i_id_inscribed, i.id_course` sin éxitos, solo llegue hasta ahí porque me imprime mal los datos y, no continúe con el resto de unir las tablas.

¿Pueden explicarme como hacer todo esto de manera correcta? O con las tablas que se puedan unir ya las otras si fuese el caso se dejaría la consulta de manera individual.

Comment: La consulta del fiddle te da los siguientes resultados: `avg_rating = 5`  / `valuations = 1` / `enrolled = 1`. ¿Qué resultados debería dar?

Comment: @A.Cedano Con el planteamiento de mi código eso resultados no da, los resultados esperados esta en la parte superior.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya he agregado un producto más que faltaba de tipo `proyect` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s2uBnyTLgTXqADtVhkgEUv/1 con esos registros que tengo ahora, deseo obtener el resultado que he detallado en la parte superior y, mi código dónde estoy optimizando en una sola consulta uniendo tablas no me muestra datos de manera correcta como lo he mencionado.

Comment: Te diste cuenta que tu intento de solucion esta mal, porque el group by esta mal? si arreglas eso, probablemente se arregle todo solo.. Los group by que usaste al principio son correctos.. el de la consulta unida, es cualquier cosa...

Comment: @gbianchi probé agregando datos de manera individual, por autor, por curso y, luego de manera general pero nada /:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todas las consultas unidas quedarían así:

```
SELECT 
        AVG(ra.rating) AS avg_rating,
        COUNT(ra.rating) AS valuations,
        COUNT(c.id_course) AS total_course
      FROM tbl_ratings ra
        LEFT JOIN tbl_courses c ON ra.id_course = c.id_course
        LEFT JOIN tbl_author a ON c.id_author = a.id_author
        LEFT JOIN tbl_inscribed i ON i.id_course = c.id_course
      WHERE 
        a.id_author=1 AND 
        i.status='Completed' AND 
        c.study_program='intensive' OR 
        c.study_program='proyect'
      GROUP BY a.id_author;
```

Pero los resultados, usando los datos del último fiddle que has compartido, serían estos:

```
avg_rating        valuations        total_course
--------------------------------------------------
    4                  2                  2
```

No se parecen a los resultados que esperas (hay dos valuations y dos cursos) y al inicio de la pregunta dices que debe haber uno de cada uno. En ese sentido revisa qué datos pusiste en el fiddle.

Algo que no queda claro es el doble criterio de `intensive` y `proyect`. Dado que no explicas el contexto, no se sabe si debe haber un doble JOIN con respecto a esos criterios o si debe haber una condición `OR`. Aquí he asumido que debe ser una condición `OR`.

Creo que con esto ya podrás salir a camino. Si analizas la consulta, simplemente he ido añadiendo las columnas del `SELECT` tomándolas de cada instrucción que tenías por separado. Del mismo modo, he ido agregando las tablas de los JOIN que eran nuevas, lo mismo que los `WHERE`. En cuanto a los `GROUP BY`, dado que se filtrará por autor, creo que es el único agrupamiento que prevalece, a no ser que quieras resultados diferenciados (varias filas) para un mismo autor.

Comment: Existen dos tipos de cursos el `intensive` que es un programa de estudio semestral y, el `proyect` son cursos dónde de aprende a crear algo en concreto por ejemplo un `ecommerce` por eso se mostraba esa información en la parte esperada

Comment: @Valentina pero ¿tú quieres promedios de todos los cursos o quieres promedios por cada tipo de curso? Eso no queda claro en el planteamiento.

Comment: el promedio global del instructor ya lo hace la tabla ratings, lo otro no se evalúa en promedios simplemente se cuenta cuántos cursos de tipo `intensive` tiene el instructor y, cuántos cursos tiene de tipo `proyect` y, cuántos alumnos se han inscripto con ese instructor/autor aquí se pasa la condición `WHERE` solo deben contar los alumnos en estado `Completed` y cuántas reseñas tienes es decir se cuenta cuántos registros de votos ha tenido ese instructor por registro no por votación `COUNT(ra.rating) valuations`

Comment: he ejecutado la consulta directamente desde la base de datos, todo parece funcionar bien, solo faltaría contar le total de alumnos inscriptos y, separar el conteo de cursos por `intensive` y `proyect`

Comment: @Valentina para contar por separado los totales de `intensive` y de `proyect` puedes agregar estas dos columnas en el `SELECT`: **`SUM(c.study_program='intensive') AS total_intensive, SUM(c.study_program='proyect') AS total_proyect`** y tendrás dos columnas cada una con la suma individual.

Comment: tendría que eliminar las condiciones pasadas en el `Where` verdad o no?

Comment: No. A no ser que no quieras filtrar por esos criterios. Las condiciones en el `WHERE` son para que te filtre por un autor específico, para que muestre solo los que están `Completed` y para que muestre sólo los `intensive` y los `proyect` ¿No te interesan esos filtros @Valentina?

Comment: y el total de alumnos inscriptos `tbl_inscribed` lo realizó como las otras demás, con el `COUNT`

Comment: yo me refiero como ya se están seleccionados desde el select como lo mencionas entonces no es necesario esto `c.study_program='intensive' OR 
        c.study_program='proyect'` porque ya está tomando la referencia por el `id_autor` o me equivoco?

Comment: El hecho de ponerlo en el SUM no significa que lo quites en el WHERE. Son 2 cosas distintas, el WHERE sirve para filtrar datos por 1 determinado criterio. Si el autor pudiera tener otro valor, por ejemplo `no intensive` y no te interesa esa fila, tendrías que mantener el `WHERE`. Eso debes decidirlo tú, en la consulta SQL yo vi todas las consultas que tenías por separado e hice una sola. ¿Por qué en una de tus consultas por separado filtrabas por esos criterios en el `WHERE`? En cuanto a contar los inscritos, en la lista del `SELECT` puedes agregar algo así: `COUNT(i.id_inscribed) AS total_i`

Comment: @Valentina, si observas tus dos últimas consultas por separado, tenían este criterio: `WHERE c.id_author=? AND c.study_program=?`  en una de ellas hacías un filtro por `intensive` y en la otra por `proyect` ... Esos dos criterios yo los incluí en la consulta única: `c.study_program='intensive' OR 
        c.study_program='proyect'` usando un criterio `OR` porque se entendía que querías filtrar por ambos criterios. No sé si me explico.